# The area of the Cycloid in polar cooredinates.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Given parameterized equation for the cycloid, $\alpha(\theta) = $ $(2(\theta - \sin\theta), 2(1-\cos\theta))$, $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

It is well known that the are of it is $\int_{0}^{2\pi}y dx = 12\pi$

But I tired this different way like the below.

Acoording to the area of the polar coordinate, $A = \int_{a}^{b} f(\theta)^2 d\theta = \int_{a}^{b} r^2 d\theta$ ($A$ is the area of the curve for $r = f(\theta)$)

I caught the idea, $r(\theta)^2 = {x(\theta)}^2 + {y(\theta)}^2$ in polar-coordinates

Given for the above case $r^2 ={f(\theta)}^2 =(2(\theta - \sin\theta))^2 +   (2(1-\cos\theta))^2 = 4\theta^2-8\theta\sin\theta + 8- 8\cos\theta$

Therefore, $A = \int_{0}^{2\pi} (4\theta^2-8\theta\sin\theta + 8- 8\cos\theta) d\theta = \frac{32}{3}\pi(3+\pi^2)$ (This is contradiction with the fact $A= 12\pi$)

What the point did I missed?

Thank you.

Comment: $\theta$ in your parametrisation $(x,y)$ is not parametrising the angle the ray makes at $0$, so you can't use this $\theta$ as your polar coordinate angle $\theta$.

Comment: The cycloid is the curve traced by a point $P$ on the side of a wheel that rolls without slipping. As mentioned in the previous comment, the $\theta$ parametrization of the cycloid is not the angle of the point $P$ with respect to the origin, but instead is the angle with respect to the moving axis of the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what I've missed! :)